# Replace value with Nan if Nan in separate row - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column in a `df` that contains numerous strings. I was to `replace` some of the strings with `Nan` but there's too many to list that can be used to `replace` these values. I have a separate column that does contain `Nan` values, which may be used to achieve this.

I want to `replace` specific strings in `Value`. Just imagine if this column contains 1000 different strings and I want to `replace` 500 with `Nan`. it would be inefficient to create a list with these unwanted strings and use it to replace with `Nan`

There is a separate column `(X)` that displays `Nan` values that can be used to `replace` rows in `Value`. So where `X` is `Nan`, replace the row in `Value` with `Nan`.

Is there an easier way to do this?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({        
    'Value' : ['B','A','X','Y','C','D','E','F','G','H','I'],
    'X' : ['A','A','A','A',np.nan,'A','A','A',np.nan,'A','A'],  
    })

df = df.loc[df['X'].eq(np.nan), df['Value']] = np.nan
print(df)
```

Intended Output:

```
   Value    X
0      B    A
1      A    A
2      X    A
3      Y    A
4      Nan  NaN
5      D    A
6      E    A
7      F    A
8      NaN  NaN
9      H    A
10     I    A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [`DataFrame.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with [`Series.isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html)

```
df=df.mask(df['X'].isna())
print(df)
```

---

```
   Value    X
0      B    A
1      A    A
2      X    A
3      Y    A
4    NaN  NaN
5      D    A
6      E    A
7      F    A
8    NaN  NaN
9      H    A
10     I    A
```

---

Also you can use [`DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) with [`Series.notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html)

```
df=df.where(df['X'].notna())
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do `dropna` + `reindex`

```
df=df.dropna().reindex(df.index)
   Value    X
0      B    A
1      A    A
2      X    A
3      Y    A
4    NaN  NaN
5      D    A
6      E    A
7      F    A
8    NaN  NaN
9      H    A
10     I    A
```